# Deriving General Solution for Depressed Cubics

Tags: cubics

I was reading An Imaginary Tale: The Story of the Square Root of Negative One and it begins with a derivation of the general solution for depressed cubics.

It begins with the format for depressed cubics:

$$x^3+px=q$$

Then says that $x$ can be written where $x=u+v$, which inserted into the original question gives

$$u^3+v^3+(3uv+p)(u+v)=q$$

It then says, "This single, rather complicated-looking equation, can be rewritten as two individually less complicated statements:"

$$3uv+p=0$$

and $$u^3+v^3=q$$

My question is why are these two equations the same as the one equation above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the identity

$$(u+v)^3 -3uv(u+v) -(u^3+v^3) = 0$$

Rewrite your depressed cubic as
$$x^3 +px-q=0$$
Substitute in $x =u+v$ as a root to get
$$(u+v)^3+p(u+v) -q=0$$
Then note the correspondence between that equation and the initial identity, so
$$q = (u^3+v^3)$$
and
$$p = -3uv$$
and hence
$$3uv+p=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$u^3+v^3+(3uv+p)(u+v)=q$$$$u^3+v^3=(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2)$$$$(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2)+(3uv+p)(u+v)=q$$$$(u+v)(u^2-uv+v^2+3uv+p)=(u+v)(u^2+v^2+2uv+p)$$$$u^2+2uv+(v^2+p)=(u-\frac{-2v+\sqrt{-4p}}{2})(u-\frac{-2v-\sqrt{-4p}}{2})$$$$(u+v)(u-\frac{-2v+\sqrt{-4p}}{2})(u-\frac{-2v-\sqrt{-4p}}{2})=q$$

Does that help?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Wojowu I wasn't sure if it did to be honest.  But I'd at least try

Comment: @Wojowu Have you been stalking me on this site?  I seem to be running into you a lot XD

Comment: I have looked at your profile and saw you had some recent activity, so I decided to comment on it.

Comment: @Wojowu Oh, thanks.  ;)  Did you read my profile description?